# DOM Parser Foreach

Tags: php, parsing, dom, screen-scraping, html-parsing

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

```
foreach($html->find('tbody.result') as $article) {
    // get retail
    $item['Retail'] = trim($article->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext);
    // get soldby
    $item['SoldBy'] = trim($article->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('alt'));

    $articles[] = $item;
}
print_r($articles);
```

Comment: what is the HTML parser you're using?

Comment: What URL are you trying to parse with?

Comment: www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B002UYSHMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B002UYSHMM');

$articles = array();

foreach($html->find('table tbody.result tr') as $article) {
  if($article->find('span.price', 0)) {
    // get retail
    $item['Retail'] = $article->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext;
    // get soldby
    if($article->find('img', 0)) $item['SoldBy'] = $article->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('alt');
    $articles[] = $item;
  }

}

print_r($articles);
```

Comment: It adds the first retail twice for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the original code should work. But simple_html_dom often breaks or behaves unpredictably.

I recommend using php's built-in DomXPath:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B002UYSHMM');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$articles = array();
foreach($xpath->query('//tbody[@class="result"]') as $tbody){
    $item = array();
    $item['Retail'] = $xpath->query('.//span[@class="price"]', $tbody)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item['SoldBy'] = $xpath->query('.//img/@alt', $tbody)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```