# PHP Simple DOM Parser Results Doubled

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

Can anyone figure out why this will double the first result in the array?

It does it no matter what page I run it on.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B001KXB7V2/');  


if($article->find('span.price', 0)) { 
// get retail 
$item['Retail'] = $article->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext; 
// get soldby 
if($article->find('img', 0))
$item['SoldBy'] = $article->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('alt'); 
$ret[] = $item; 
}
```

Comment: Why not use some indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782211/dom-parser-foreach/7782374#7782374)! You are picking up the price that is in the "box" labeled "Price at a glance" as well as the normal prices listed with the seller information.

Try this:

```
foreach($html->find('div.resultsset table tbody.result tr') as $article) {
  if($article->find('span.price', 0)) { 
    // get retail 
    $item['Retail'] = $article->find('span.price', 0)->plaintext; 
    // get soldby 
    if($article->find('img', 0))
    $item['SoldBy'] = $article->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('alt');
    $ret[] = $item;
  }
}
```